# Дата создания файлов в CentOs 7 устанавливается 1 января 1970 года, почему?

Tags: файлы, дата, centos, файловая-система

На одном из серверов с операционной системой CentOs 7 дата создания файлов(как и дата последнего доступа и изменения) для новых файлов устанавливается равной "1 января 1970 года", почему так?

Такое поведение как при создании новых файлов по ssh/sftp(использую Dolphin встроенный в Kubuntu 20-ой версии), так и при создании файлов из php(выполнение кода вроде $fp=fopen("адрес_файла","w");fwrite($fp,"что-записать");fclose($fp);)

При этом выполнение в командной строке команды date - система возвращает реальное корректно установленное текущее время.

Как устранить такое поведение и сделать чтобы для новых файлов устанавливалось корректное значение даты создания(а так же даты последнего доступа и изменения).

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Чтобы локализовать проблему, уточните такие вещи. Напишите вывод `stat (проблемный файл)` и название файловой системы, где лежит файл. Файловая система случайно не подмонтирована через Самбу или другим способом (команда `mount` в помощь)? Вообще напишите выхлоп mount. Если выполнить `touch /tmp/test; stat /tmp/test` - такая же проблема?

Comment: Вроде бы ничего не сделал(кроме команды синхронизации времени), хотя у новых файлов сейчас пишет stat upload/iblock/fc9/test.txt Файл: «upload/iblock/fc9/test.txt» Размер: 2 Блоков: 8 Блок В/В: 4096 обычный файл Устройство: fd02h/64770d Inode: 4689635 Ссылки: 1 Доступ: (0644/-rw-r--r--) Uid: (0/ root) Gid: (0/ root) Доступ: 2022-10-27 15:10:31.558937292 +0300 Модифицирован: 2022-10-27 15:10:31.569937131 +0300 Изменён: 2022-10-27 15:10:31.810933576 +0300 Создан: -. У старых файлов ещё доступ и изменён пустое. Тогда вопрос почему дата создания не проставляется?

Comment: Возможно, какой-то скрипт модифицирует. Например, вирус. Вариантов масса.

Comment: Не понял в чём было дело с датой изменения и доступа. Пачки файлов созданных до вчерашнего дня без дат. Сейчас при создании файлов эти даты проставляются. А касаемо даты создания - посмотрел она и на других серверах не проставляется. Можно как то сделать чтобы эта дата тоже устанавливалась?

Comment: Дату создания Linux не пишет

Comment: Ок, понял. Может быть подскажете тогда зачем она нужна в sftp клиентах?

Comment: Есть разные ОС, разные файловые системы. Где-то пишется дата создания. sftp не привязан к какой-то ОС, поэтому показывает то что есть, даже если этого нет

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!